# Unable to restart Apache hue running on docker container

Tags: docker, supervisord, hue

Currently executing apache hue on docker
Done some changes on hue.ini file which requires hue restart and for doing that running the command

```
./build/env/bin/supervisor
```

However this command is failing to run and throwing below error -

```
[2023-07-27 06:16:06 -0700] [425] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2023-07-27 06:16:06 -0700] [425] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8888)
[2023-07-27 06:16:06 -0700] [425] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-07-27 06:16:07 -0700] [425] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8888)
```

Tried to kill the process running on 8888 port but still no luck , can anyone please suggest what would be the way to resolve this issue

Update -1

After running the docker stop commands , followed the below steps
Started docker command to start hue

```
docker run -it -p 8900:8888 gethue/hue:latest
```

After that changed the hue.ini file to keep the hive server details , dummy value is provide just to check whether the changes are reflected in hue UI

```
 [[[hive]]]
   name=Hive
   interface=hiveserver2

[beeswax]
# Host where HiveServer2 is running.
# If Kerberos security is enabled, use fully-qualified domain name (FQDN).
hive_server_host=localhost11
# Binary thrift port for HiveServer2.
hive_server_port=10000
```

Then executed the command to restart hue server

```
./build/env/bin/hue runserver 0.0.0.0:8900
```

This command didn't show any error but UI also didn't show the updated values in hue.ini file

So my query is exactly what are the steps to be followed to restart hue service after changing in hue file

But confused between all these 3

```
./build/env/bin/supervisor
./build/env/bin/hue runserver
./build/env/bin/hue runcpserver
```